# discussing personal research

Tags: discussion

I assume that I am correct in thinking that the site does not support discussing personal research, is there some online place where we can discuss our research ?

I ask this question here cause I could not find any such place on google.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

Note that if one comes across an issue while doing research, they are welcome to ask it as long as the question is working within the framework of modern mainstream physics. However, especially since discussion questions are not allowed here, discussing one's research usually leads to a question that is either open ended, broad, or non mainstream.

We sometimes discuss research in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar), though we rarely talk of the exact details<sup>1</sup> of the research that is being done, people are free to do so. (Just don't annoy people)

<sup>1. Modern cutting-edge research is usually of the kind that one needs an appreciable depth of knowledge in that subfield to understand it.</sup>

Comment: Actually I have been formulating a conceptual machine generating energy in a non conventional way and I think that I can really use some fresh eyes and thoughts. Is there some place where I can discuss my ideas ?

Comment: @rijulgupta Like I said, [chat]. Quora may work too, if you want to do it off-site, but they usually frown on stuff like this.

Answer (score 6):

One thing I like to say to people with questions like this is that you keep explaining why you would like to have your question on Physics.SE (and we get that, we really do), but you have not explained why Physics.SE would benefit by hosting your question.

No matter how good *your question* might be, to allow this category would be to open our doors to an endless stream of low quality musing by every Tom Dick and Harry who thinks he knows something.

Comment: I am not asking for an allowance of the category, I asked this question to find if there is some place where I could actually discuss some findings online.